Express return error if body greater than 1mb
Hello guys I'm trying to create a middleware in express
function logResponseBody(req, res, next) {
  var oldWrite = res.write,
      oldEnd = res.end;

  const maxSize = 1023;

  var chunks = [];

  res.write = function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(new Buffer(chunk));

    oldWrite.apply(res, arguments);
  };

  res.end = function (chunk) {
    if (chunk)
      chunks.push(new Buffer(chunk));

    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8');
    console.log(req.path, body);

    if (responseSize > maxSize) {
       // here return a status code 314 and a message the response body is to big
    }

    oldEnd.apply(res, arguments);
  };

  next();
}

app.use(logResponseBody);

What I'm trying to achive is the check if response body is greater than 1mb then return a custom response with error message.
I have a part of the code but when I try to return the response with res.end it gets stuck in the loop

I don't see a loop. Where does it get stuck? How did you deduce it got stuck?

It seems that responseSize is not defined anywhere before you compare it with maxSize. Are you sure this code is running properly?
